# Jenkins Library / Groovy Script - Wrap Code dynamically

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm developing a Jenkins shared library right now.
I wasn't able to figure how to easily "wrap" a code inside a function without copy-pasting the whole code. For example: If a developer sets a value to true, then I want to wrap the whole code inside a function. Right now I want to use this to allow e.g. the gitlabIntegration to be turned off from the Jenkinsfile.

Example:

```
// vars/stageWrapper.groovy
def call(Map parameters = [:], body) {
    stage(stageName) {
        if (pushtoGitlab) {
            gitlabCommitStatus(stageName) {
                if (!containerName) body()
                else {
                    container(containerName) {
                        body()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!containerName) body()
            else {
                container(containerName) {
                    body()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- let the user select if the stage should be pushed to gitlab via the gitlabCommitStatus wrapper.
- switch to a specified container or use default container (if none is specified)

To realize this I currently repeat the code, which I really don't like...

Is there any way of achieving the same, but without repeating the same code over and over?

Thank You!

Comment: what don't you want to repreat? Also show the relevant code of your `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction`

Comment: Thanks, I just did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy you can reuse a Closure in different DSL-Builders by setting it's `delegate` to builder's `delegate`.

Something like this should work:

```
def containerNameBody = { body ->
  if (!containerName) 
    body()
  else
    container(containerName) {
      body()
    }
}

def call(Map parameters = [:], body) {
    stage(stageName) {
        containerNameBody.delegate = delegate

        if (pushtoGitlab)
            gitlabCommitStatus(stageName) {
               containerNameBody body
            }
        else            
            containerNameBody body       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In Jenkins the closure /delegate is a tad different to handle, since it's inside your function, but I managed to get it working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about following approach to pass down the param into function, then decide how to do inside the function by the param value.

```
def gitHub(gitHubOn) {

}

def gitLab(gitLabOn) {

}

def call(Map parameters = [:], body){
   //some code....
   foo=bar
   gitLab(parameters.gitLabOn)
   gitHub(parameters.gitHubOn)
   body()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I'm talking about fixed wrappers. E.g. the wrappers of the GitLab Jenkins Plugin, so I don't think I'm able to edit the functionality of these wrappers. 
I'm sorry that I failed to make this a bit clearer. I've updated the question with a more concrete example now.